# Send a message at only one user subribed at a one topic of mqtt Broker

Tags: java, mqtt

I apologize if the question may seem silly.

I have a mqtt broker on which I have for example the topic "ChatBox/Chat_1",
on this topic there are subcribed many users, but if the master that is subcribed so "ChatBox" wanted to send a message to a single user in Chat_1 without the others receiving it, there is a method or not?

Comment: add more details !!

Comment: @hardilib is completely correct that what you asked for isn’t possible, but hasn’t offered any sort of hint of a possible way of trying to solve your problem. It’s not that there is a protocol-busting method for the master to send messages to individual clients, it’s more like a pattern or approach for arranging client topics: to achieve the ability to send messages to individual clients what you will have to do is do is give each client their own personal topic (as well as the general topic) and then the master can send them messages on that topic.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad that on this platform there is also someone, instead of immediately putting -1, you understand that not everyone is an expert programmer, but that someone can also ask questions that may seem silly given that he is having a self-study approach to a topic.
After a while I realized that the only method was what you suggested to me and I used a registration form to acquire user data and use their username for both the client and the personal topic.

Answer (score 2):

MQTT Messages are published to topics, not individual clients/users. All clients subscribed to the topic will receive all messages published to that topic.

There is no way to send a message to a specific client without writing a totally custom MQTT broker (which would then be in violation of the spec)